# Overriding method causes redundant, duplicate annotations in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

After recent update, AndroidStudio would put these redundant--sort of duplicate annotations when overriding method (by using Code > Generate > Override Methods) like blow:

```
@Nullable
@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

I don't need these `@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable` `and @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`. Just only with `@Nullable` or with `@NotNull` is sufficient. Every time I override a method, I must delete such annotation manually, and it's painful.

Previous AndroidStudio's behavior (ideal):

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Are there any way to avoid this behavior of recent AndroidStudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Thank for @DavidLee's answer, the solution is around that preference.

There is **Configure Annotations** button when you select Editor > Inspections > Probable bugs > Nullability bugs > Nullability problems > @NotNull/@Nullable problems. And you push the button, a popup window of Nullable/Notnull Configuration opens, in the window you can set @Nullable and @NotNull pointers.

[image: screenshot]

`org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable` and `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` are selected by default. If you set them to `androidx.annotation.Nullable` and `androidx.annotaion.NonNull`, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to disable them by the following way:

**Preferences**/**Settings** >> **Editor** >> **Inspections** >> **Java** >> **Probable bugs** >> **Nullability problems** >> *Uncheck the ones you don't want*

[image: Nullability]

Comment: Your answer didn't solve my problem directly, but I figured out my solution owing to your answer. Thank you!